# Why am I getting this error: "data definition has no type or storage class"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bison, cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE {
    char* name;
    int val;
    struct NODE* next;
};
typedef struct NODE Node;

Node *head, *tail;
head = (Node*) malloc( sizeof( Node ) ); //line 21
```

And I compiling like this:

```
cc -g -c -o file.tab.o file.tab.c
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
file.y:21:1 warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like the line

```
head = (Node*) malloc( sizeof( Node ) ); //line 21
```

is outside the `main()` function. You can't do that, because you can't execute code outside  functions. The only thing you can do at global scope is *declaring variables.* Just move it inside the `main()` or any other function, and the problem should go away.

(PS: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) on why you shouldn't type-cast `malloc`)

Comment: fought with this for an hour...so silly...now I'm embarrassed lol, thanks!!

Comment: @streppel, I am getting the same error when I write `dev_t dev; dev = MKDEV(300, 0)`, instead if I write `dev_t dev = MKDEV(300, 0)`, my module runs fine. Why is that? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @Dr.Essen `MKDEV` is a macro. The result value is precomputed at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code inside a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE {
    char* name;
    int val;
    struct NODE* next;
};
typedef struct NODE Node;

main(){
    Node *head, *tail;
    head = (Node*) malloc( sizeof( Node ) ); //line 21
}
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to call `malloc` when you aren't executing inside of a function. If you wrap that inside a `main` function, for example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Node *head, *tail;
    head = (Node*) malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    /* ... do other things ... */
    return 0;
}
```

… it works just fine. GCC's error is a little cryptic, but the problem is basically that you're trying to initialize a variable with something that isn't a constant, which is impossible outside of a function.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the malloc and variable declarations in a main function, and delete the cast on malloc. It should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    struct NODE
    {
        char* name;
        int val;
        struct NODE* next;
    };

    typedef struct NODE Node;

    Node *head, *tail;
    head = malloc( sizeof(Node) ); //line 21
}
```

Comment: You probably want to move the struct definition (and its associated `typedef`) out of `main`, if you want them to be reusable by other parts of the project.