# Compiler shows data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: c, variables, error-handling, scope, queue

I'm trying to write a code that performs addition, deletion operations on queue using array.
I defined two int type data front and rear for pointing at starting and last position of queue in following way :-

```
// outside of main function
#define MAX 100
int queue[MAX];
int front;
int rear;
front = -1;
rear = -1;
```

but compiler(visual studion with gcc compiler) shows data defination has no type or storage class but when I modified code a little bit compiler shows no error

```
//outside of main function
#define MAX 100
int queue[MAX];
int front = -1, rear = -1;
```

I don't know why this is happening.
I will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: You **must** initialize a variable _outside a function_ like this: `int front = -1;`.  `int front; front = -1;` is improper.

Comment: It is more usefull to create a struct and inside there put your variables front and near with the value you want and create an array with the same type of the struct and continuing like that.Or you can have the array inside of struct and also you can put another variables that will be usefull for you later on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting this error: "data definition has no type or storage class"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906190/why-am-i-getting-this-error-data-definition-has-no-type-or-storage-class)